# Connecting sql server to Microsoft Visio

Tags: sql-server, database-connection, visio

I want to draw the database schema from sql server into microsoft visio. 
I have visio professional 2013.

i select software and database-->Crow's Foot Database Notation/Chen's databas Notation/ Dataflow Model Diagram. But then I do not find any database option for which i need to reverse engineer.

I can select Data menu-->Link Data to Shapes option. her I can connect to my sql database but I get specific rows but not the full schema and its connection with many tables.

Can anyone guide me here ??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Reverse Engineering option was removed from Visio 2013. 
Use previous version of Visio to reverse-engineer a database.